# Javascript error of document click function with promise

Tags: javascript

I have the following function and I want to maximize the performance using Js Promise or maybe async with await. But obviously what I have done in function `f()` called from the `click` function is wrong.

The flow of the following function is

1. Check if the item is existing from the `div`
2. If exist, execute the `else` statement and finish
3. If the item is not exist, it will load the older data from another function named `loadOlderMsg(param1, param2)` and I want to wait until this function is loaded finish until the next step.
4. If the `loadOlderMsg(param1, param2)` does not found the data, continue load this function again until the data is found.
5. After the data is found, run the `else` statement function.

**Edit :** However, there are 2 cases when I run the following code.

1. If the item is exists, the `$parentDiv` does not scroll but the animation of background is worked.
2. If the item is not exists, I get an error from the console.log show `cannot read the property top of undefined`  <--- $innerItem

I appreciated the help. Thanks

```
// Click on something and do some animation thing if it is found 
// else load and get the data then only do the animation thing 
$(document).on('click', '.msg-quote', function(){
    let quoteid = $(this).find('.msg-sender').attr('data-reply-to');
    if($('.talk-element').attr('data-ww-msgid')){
        
        let $parentDiv = $('.wchat-wrapper');
        let $innerItem = $('.talk-element[data-ww-msgid="'+quoteid+'"]').position();

        if($innerItem == undefined){
            //not found, need load older msg
            let xxx = f().then(()=>{
                alert('Success');
            }, ()=>{
                alert('Failed');
            });

        }else{
           // Item exist then do myThing 
           $parentDiv.animate({
              scrollTop: $innerItem.top - 150
           }, 500);

           $('.talk-element[data-ww-msgid="'+quoteid+'"]').css('background' , '#E2E2E2');
              setTimeout(()=>{
           $('.talk-element[data-ww-msgid="'+quoteid+'"]')
              .css({
                 'transition'    : 'all 1s ease',
                 'background'    : 'unset'
              });
           }, 1000);
        } // End of else
    } 
});

function f(){
    console.log('This function is called'); // This console.log never called
    return Promise.resolve(function(){
        loadOlderMsg(param1, param2); // I want load this function and wait until it finish
    });
}
```

Comment: If `f()` is never called, it means `$('.talk-element').attr('data-ww-msgid')` is falsy or `$innerItem == undefined` is false.

Comment: I edited my question here sorry with the 2 real cases scenario

Comment: I don't see a reason why issue 2 would happen. I'd suggest putting `console.log($innerItem)` just after the assignment and again just before `$parentDiv.animate`.